# How would I generate a random number of processes and priorities?

Tags: linux, bash, unix

So far I have the code to generate a random number between 10 and 30, but I have NO IDEA how to find print a random process that many times and also give these processes random priorities. Perhaps, this is general lack of understanding, but I have been looking at articles for hours now.

```
echo "Generating random processes between 10 and 30"

min = 10;
max = 30;

range = $(($max-$min+1));

for i in {$range)
```

Comment: `shuf -n X -e $(ps -Ao pid=)` generates X random PIDs, and `shuf -n X -e -- {-20..19}` generates X random niceness values. With `nice`, you can change a process' niceness (*priority*), guess these are all you need

Comment: Watch out! You have spaces around `=`. The command `min = 10`  does anything else but assigning 10 to `min`. https://www.shellcheck.net/ your script for an explanation.

Comment: @oguzismail Thanks! I'm going to try it!

Comment: @oguzismail Would you know how to add add these to a text file too?